# Making Axes logarithmic in 3d plots

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I've been trying to get loglog plots in 3D, but to no avail. My initial approach was to take the logarithm inside the plot i.e

```
Plot3D[Log[10,function[a, b]],{a, 1, 100000},{b, 1, 1000000}]
```

but now I'm looking for a way to logarithm-ise the axes as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Something that you could do would be to get the logarithm outside the plot, and then use the `LogTicks` (from the LevelScheme package) to rescale the axes. This worked for me

Comment: @Sosi why don't you post that (with details) as an answer?

Comment: @Sosi, thanks, but I'm very new to mathematica and unfamiliar with the LogTicks command. Could you give me any tips on using it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Edit: The new package to install for this comes from the `CustomTicks` *subpackage* of the `SciDraw` package (formerly, `LevelScheme`).

You first have to install the [SciDraw package](http://scidraw.nd.edu/), it's worth it if you produce a lot of figures. You can see how to do it on the [SciDraw guide](http://scidraw.nd.edu/beta/SciDrawGuide.pdf).

Load the package that you will be using

```
Get["CustomTicks`"]
```

Assign a function and do the 3D plot:

```
function = Log[10, a x + b /. a -> 1];
Plot3D[function, {x, 1, 3}, {b, -1, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, 3}, {-1, 3}, {-1, 1}}, 
 Ticks -> {LogTicks[10, 1, 3], LogTicks[10, -1, 3], LogTicks[10, -1, 1]}
]
```

This would produce this figure:

[image]

If you wanted to have the yy axis with linear ticks instead you could adapt the `Ticks` option above. Here, I also changed the `PlotRange` specification and added an `AxesLabel` so that it is easier to see.

```
Plot3D[function, {x, 1, 3}, {b, -1, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, 2}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}}, 
 Ticks -> {LogTicks[10, 1, 3], LinTicks[-1, 0, 0.25, 5], 
   LogTicks[10, -1, 3]}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

The `SciDraw` (and more specifically the `CustomTicks`) package is really nice to do these things!

Comment: This helped alot, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Maybe still more for future versions of Mathematica but the option ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Reverse"} has been introduced for Gauges, Histograms and BarCharts in version 9.  Unluckily, it fails in  number of instances.  I reported this as an error a while ago.  Since the implementation is very general, I cannot see why it should not also become available for all other Plot-related functions.

Comment: LevelScheme uses the same method that Martin Wijaya uses in his answer, but it adds features to make the plot look more professional. On page 4 of LevelScheme's CustomTickGuide.pdf, it states how to turn logarithmic plots into linear plots, which is how LevelScheme functions.

Comment: I wonder why I even use the replacement function in my answer...

Comment: @ Sosi, I was trying to utilize your recommendation in here to come up with a 3d surface plot of a two-variable function. The only difference that I have is only one of my x or y axes has logarithmic scale as well as my z axis. I have installed the package required to make use of *Ticks* option. However, I am receiving error message saying, "Tick specification must be a list or a function" even though I am using exactly the same format as you did in here in my Mathematica 8.0. Do you know what could possibly be the reason for it? Do you recommend me posting a new question? Thanks in advance,

Comment: @Benjamin - I had no problem (other than having to reinstall the package). Using my example above I adapted `PlotRange -> {{1, 2}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 0}}` (just to see better), and if I wanted to make the yy axis linear I changed `Ticks` to `Ticks -> {LogTicks[10, 1, 3], LinTicks[-1, 0, 0.25, 5], 
  LogTicks[10, -1, 3]}` and it worked. I will update my answer with the new  package stuff and to add this information.

Answer (score 11):

`LogTicks` is really nice.  However, if you might wish to avoid another package or have more control over the final output, here is a template.  As mentioned in a comment above, I actually hope that `ScalingFunctions` will be fully implemented in the future.

```
function[a_, b_] := Log[10, a + b]

Plot3D[Log[10, function[#^10 &@a, #^10 &@b]], {a, Log10@1, 
  Log10@100000}, {b, Log10@1, Log10@100000}, 
 Ticks -> {Table[{y, ToString[Round[10^y, 0.001]]}, {y, Log[10, 1], 
     Log[10, 100000]}], 
   Table[{y, 
     ToString[
      Round[10^y, 0.001] // ScientificForm // TraditionalForm]}, {y, 
     Log[10, 0.001], Log[10, 100000]}], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use `ScalingFunctions`. (It appears red in version 10, but still works.)

```
function = Log[10, a x + b /. a -> 1];
Plot3D[function, {x, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}, PlotLabel -> "Normal"]
Plot3D[function, {x, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}, 
    ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, Identity, "Log"}, PlotLabel -> "Log"]
```

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't apply `Log` preliminarily if you use `ScalingFunctions -> "Log"`, just plot the objective function as usual: `Plot3D[Evaluate[a x + b /. a -> 1], {x, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, Identity, "Log"}, PlotLabel -> "Log"]`.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this is what you want:

Let say the function is describe as:

```
z=Log10[x]+Log10[y]
```

Where under normal plot, it will give you a curvy surface while on the log plot will give you a rectangular surface.

And you want to rescale the axes of x,y without changing the function of x and y.

Under normal circumstances, you will plot it like below to give you the curvy surface,

```
Plot3D[z, {x, 1, 1000}, {y, 1, 1000}]
```

[image: Surface under normal plot]

In order to change it into a rectangular surface due to the change in the x and y axes scale, you can do the following

```
Plot3D[z/.{x->10^a,y->10^b},{a,0,3},{b,0,3}]
```

[image: Surface by changing the axes]

In order to change the axes from a and b to x and y again and keep the log scale, Since I know that if a = 1 then x = 10, then i can just rename the axes with ticks function.you can do the following

```
Plot3D[z /. {x -> 10^a, y -> 10^b}, {a, 0, 3}, {b, 0, 3}, Ticks -> {Table[{i,10^i},{i,0, 6}], Table[{i, 10^i}, {i, 0, 6}], Automatic}]
```

[image: Surface by changing the scale]

I hope this is what are you looking for.