# User defined scaling function

Tags: plotting

I would like to change the scaling of the x-axis by defining a scaling function.
My example is more complicated than the following but I take this one because it is simpler.

What I would like to plot here is the function $x \mapsto x$ in function of $x$ but with a rescaling of the x-axis such that when $x=Log(2)$, the x-axis shows the value 1.

```
f[x_] := x/Log[2]

Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, ScalingFunctions -> {f, None}]
```

However this code doesn't work.

How to make it work ?

Comment: @kglr it works ! So I must give mathematica the inverse of the function as well to make it work. Why is it so ?

Comment: StarBuck, that's how `ScalingFunctions` work (see [ScalingFunctions >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScalingFunctions.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to give the result you want in v10.1:

```
f[x_] := x/Log[2];

Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, ScalingFunctions -> {f, InverseFunction[f]}]

Show[%, Ticks -> Automatic, GridLines -> {{Log[2]}, {1}}]
```

[image]

#### Get Coordinates Tool

If you use the Get Coordinates Tool on the plot above, accessed by right-clicking, you will see that it gives ~= {0.693, 1.00} for the point at which the grid lines cross.  I consider this desirable.  However if you prefer to have the Get Coordinates Tool return ~= {0.693, 0.693} it would be more direct to skip [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) and use a tick generating function directly:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks[{InverseFunction[f], f}]}, 
 GridLines -> {{Log[2]}, {Log[2]}}]
```

It would be possible to make the coordinates of this second plot match those of the first using [`CoordinatesToolOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinatesToolOptions.html) but if that's the desire it's simpler to use `Show`.

#### "Elephant in the room"

I interpreted this question as that of making `ScalingFunctions` work, and answered that, resulting in a somewhat convoluted solution with `Show`.  If that wasn't the actual intent of the question it should be noted that one could scale the function itself directly with essentially the same result:

```
Plot[f @ x, {x, 0, 1}, GridLines -> {{Log[2]}, {1}}]
```

Comment: Thank you. Just to understand, why do I need to put the Ticks->Automatic (indeed without it, the rescaling doesn't show up). But I would like to understand, is it somehow a "refresh" of the x-value to take in account the rescaling ?

Comment: @StarBucK More or less, yes.  Normally scaling doesn't change the *labeling* but rather the *position* of the labels.  Consider e.g. `LogPlot[x, {x, 0, 50}]` -- the axis is still labeled 0 to 50.  But since you want to change the range of the axis itself you want to force relabeling, as in `Show[LogPlot[x, {x, 0, 50}], Ticks -> Automatic]` where the axis is now labeled zero to four (approximately).