# Plot solution to damped driven pendulum in $(-\pi,\pi)$

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, modular-arithmetic

I'm solving the damped driven pendulum:

```
{γ, g, ω} = {0.5, 1.5, 2/3};
{X0, V0} = {0.6184, 0.};
tmax = 1000;
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + γ x'[t] + Sin[x[t]] == g Cos[ω t], x[0] == X0, x'[0] == V0}, x, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]
sol1[t_] := x[t] /. sol[[1]]
sol2[t_] := x'[t] /. sol[[1]]
```

I then want to plot the solution $(x,x')$ constraining $x$ to the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$. I came with modulo to make one part $(-2\pi,0)$, the other $(0,2\pi)$, and then restrict the range to $(-\pi,\pi)$. First, it is inelegant. Second, I end with a gap in the middle that even with a big number of `PlotPoints` I cannot get rid of.

```
ParametricPlot[{{Mod[sol1[t], -2 π], sol2[t]}, {Mod[sol1[t], 2 π], sol2[t]}}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> {{-π, π}, {-3, 3}}, PlotPoints -> 500]
```

[image]

Using an alternative formulation for modulo:

```
normalize[angle_?(NumericQ[#] && Im[#] == 0 &)] := angle - 2 Pi Floor[(angle + Pi)/(2 Pi)]
```

to plot

```
ParametricPlot[{normalize@sol1[t], sol2[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> {{-π, π}, {-3, 3}}, PlotPoints -> 500]
```

I get redundant horizontal lines:

[image]

How to make such plot elegantly?

Comment: `PlotPoints -> 600, MaxRecursion -> 8`

Comment: I asked a very similar question about plotting the DDP some years ago:  [Unexpected behavior of `Exclusions` in `ParametricPlot`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170832/unexpected-behavior-of-exclusions-in-parametricplot).  Some good ideas there as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps it's easier to use `NDSolveValue` and `Mod[...,2 Pi,-Pi]` with offset:

```
{γ, g, ω} = {0.5, 1.5, 2/3};
{X0, V0} = {0.6184, 0.};
tmax = 1000;
X = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + γ x'[t] + Sin[x[t]]==g Cos[ω t], x[0] == X0, x'[0] == V0},x, {t, 0, tmax},MaxSteps -> Infinity]

ParametricPlot[ {Mod[X[t], 2 Pi, -Pi], X'[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image]